# swipe one cell at a time in Swipeable in react-native,on swipe of another previous should be closed automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-gesture-handler, react-swipeable-views

I am new to react native ,working with Swipeable which is present in "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable".currently on opening the second item ,the first item still shows open.
requirement is to open one item at a time,written my own component for this.code and issue attached.Anyone having any idea or reference?.

```
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";

const Sample = ({ data, index }) => {
  const swipeRef = React.useRef();
  let row: Array<any> = [];
  let prevOpenedRow;
  const rightSwipeActions = (progress, dragX) => {
    return (
      <>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClickAdd}>
          <View style={[styles.swipeButtonView, styles.swipeRemoveButton]}>
            <Animated.Text style={styles.swipeButtonText}>
              {"add"}
            </Animated.Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClickremove}>
          <View style={[styles.swipeButtonView, styles.swipeModifyButton]}>
            <Animated.Text style={styles.swipeButtonText}>
              {"remove"}
            </Animated.Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
    );
  
  };
  const onClickadd = () => {
    onClickaddButton();
    closeSwipable();
  };

  const onClickremove = () => {
    onClickModifyremove();
    closeSwipable();
  };

  const closeSwipable = (index) => {
    if (prevOpenedRow && prevOpenedRow !== row[index]) {
      prevOpenedRow.close();
    }
    prevOpenedRow = row[index];
  };

  return (
    <Swipeable
      friction={2}
      renderRightActions={rightSwipeActions}
      ref={(ref) => (row[index] = ref)}
      leftThreshold={80}
      rightThreshold={40}
      onSwipeableOpen={closeSwipable(index)}
      key={data?.TI}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "white",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        activeOpacity={1}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Swipeable>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps me a lot with similar problem: [link](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/764#issuecomment-635552081)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).